# How to change the file foramt from unix to windows in oracle apex - using owa_util.mime_header / wpg_docload.download_file

Tags: sql, oracle

I implemented a simple text file download to oracle apex. 
using: 
owa_util.mime_header('text/html', false); 
wpg_docload.download_file(l_file);

I need a CR LF (Windows) not LF (Unix) in the generated file. 
CR = carriage return ;-)

Where can i change the output file format?

Thanks!

Comment: Most editors have an option to quickly change between those. I believe notepad++ might have the features you're asking for

Comment: Yes, thats right. But i need the correct file format from beginning. i cant change it in an editor.

Comment: Any editor should be able to spot `\r`, `\n`, or `\r\n` and be able to replace them. If anything, just go into an editor, replace all the CR/LF endings with CRLF